# How to sort in biblatex by name, year, order of appearance

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I am using biblatex with the following settings:

- `backend=biber`
- `style=authoryear`
- `citestyle=authoryear-comp`
- `sorting=nyt`

This works as expected, but I find the `sorting=nyt` to be suboptimal. I would rather sort by name, year, and then order of appearance in the text.

Why? The title of the paper has little relevance for the reader, but it still determines the order of disambiguation marks "a", "b", etc when there are multiple citations in a year. For example, imagine the two following publications by John Doe, both published in year 2017, with the titles

- "Emerging evidence for x"
- "Another piece of evidence for x"

Now, even if I cite the first paper (Emerging evidence) first and the second paper last (Another piece of evidence), the first will be cited as Doe (2017b) and the second will be Doe (2017a). Looks stupid to me.

What is the best way to have biblatex sort the citations in order name, year, order of appearance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look in the file `biblatex.def` to find definitions of the different sortings. Based on a combination of the `sorting=none` sorting and `sorting=nyt` I came up with the following which I call `sorting=nyc` (`c` for `\citeorder`).

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{nyc}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{\citeorder}
}
```

Just put this snippet after the `\usepackage[sorting=nyc,...]{biblatex}` command. Don't forget to specify `sorting=nyc` in the biblatex options.

*Edit:* `presort` and `sortkey` included in the beginning as suggested and explained by @moewe in two comments below.

*Edit 2:* Bugfixed code to really give order `nyc`. Thanks to @moewe for alerting me to the mistake.

Comment: +1) If you want your new scheme to be more in line with the standard schemes, you might want to add `\sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }` (modulo line break) to the begin.

Comment: Thanks @moewe! Can you please clarify what improvement that would bring apart from being more in line with standard schemes?

Comment: This places `presort` and `sortkey` higher up in the sort order. `sortkey` is some kind of 'master sort key' as the documentation says, it can be set from the `.bib` file to override any automatic sorting. `presort` can be used to sort different entry types differently. In particular then, the`sortkey` field in the `.bib` as well as the `\DeclarePresort` command work as advertised instead of not at all with your current setting.

Comment: As pointed out in http://golatex.de/sortierung-authoryear-gleicher-autorundjahr-problem-citeundbib-t19755.html the sorting scheme here is actually `ync` and not `nyc`.

Comment: Thanks @moewe for highlighting that! I noted the error and fixed it in my own document, but forgot to update here.

Comment: For biber version >= 3.8: `\DeclareSortingScheme` should be replaced by `\DeclareSortingTemplate`

Comment: FYI the option `sortcites=false` is needed to ensure that multi-citations are not sorted.