# How to use order of appearance for authoryear style citations with multiple entries having same year and author?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, harvard-style

I am using authoryear (Harvard) style citations and have multiple sources with the same year and author which automatically adds a letter to the end (like "Author (Year a)" and "Author (Year b)".

These seem to be in alphabetical order instead of order of appearance, resulting in citing "Author (Year d)" before everything else.

Here is a demo document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testing.bib}

\begin{document}
Citing \textcite{b} and \textcite{a}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With "testing.bib" containing:

```
@misc{a,
    title = {A},
    author = {Doe, John},
    year = {2020}
}
@misc{b,
    title = {B},
    author = {Doe, John},
    year = {2020}
}
```

The resulting document looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the document generated by the code above]

Is there a way to instruct BibLatex to sort these letters by order of appearance instead?

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/389159/35864.

Comment: @moewe The custom "nyc" sorting fixes this issue, thank you!